# Is there a way to have reset command reset input settings without clearing the screen?

Tags: bash, terminal

I have a problem with an application, dosemu2 in `-dumb -td -kt` mode, which messes with my MATE terminal window. (Either directly in the MATE terminal window, or with GNU screen between them.) After I terminate the application using a signal (`killall -v dosemu.bin`) or by crashing it, the bash shell that's left running in this window will receive lots of text data as the MATE terminal window receives mouse cursor movement data.

I found that I can restore the normal working of the shell by running the `reset` command, and sometimes also by running only `tset`. However, `tset` is hit or miss in that it sometimes clears the screen and also sometimes doesn't reset the mouse input spam. `reset` always resets the mouse input, but it also always clears the screen which I would like to avoid. `reset -I` does not clear the screen but also does not fix the mouse input problem.

Is there a way to have what `reset` does in terms of disabling the mouse input, but without clearing the visible screen area?

I previously wrote about this in the dosemu2 discussions, here: https://github.com/dosemu2/dosemu2/discussions/2061

Here's an image showing the mouse data entered as text at the end:

[image: Terminal window receiving mouse movement data as text after terminating dosemu2.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `reset` command is a shortcut to `tput reset`. The documentation for this command says,

> **`reset`** […] the terminal's reset strings will be output if  present
> (`rs1`, `rs2`, `rs3`, `rf`). If the reset strings are not present, but initialization strings are, the initialization strings will be output. Otherwise, reset acts identically to init.

So, to find out what sequences the `reset` command actually sends to the terminal to switch it out of the various modes it might be in, we need to look at the settings for `rs1`, `rs2`, `rs3`, and `rf`.

At this point, instead of `reset`, you could try `tput rs1`, and `tput rs2`, and `tput rs3`, and `tput rf` to see which one - if any - resolves the issue without clearing the screen.

However, continuing on with the dive. In `man terminfo` the documentation simply writes,

> ```
> reset_1string        rs1        r1         reset string
> reset_2string        rs2        r2         reset string
> reset_3string        rs3        r3         reset string
> reset_file           rf         rf         name of reset file
> ```

This means we need to revert to the terminfo database directly

```
infocmp | grep -Po '\w+=[^,]*' | grep -E '^(rs[123]|rf)='
```

For me this returns two entries,

```
rs1=\Ec
rs2=\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>
```

These can be read directly with `\E` representing <kbd>Escape</kbd>, and rewritten as `printf` sequences:

```
printf '\ec'
printf '\e[!p'; printf '\e[?3;4l'; printf '\e[4l'; printf '\e>'
```

Finding out what the escape sequences actually mean is probably beyond the scope of this answer but here are some

```
ESC c          # Reset and clear screen
ESC [!p
ESC [?e;4l
ESC [4l
ESC >
```

And finally, it's been noted that there is a [recent commit](https://github.com/dosemu2/dosemu2/commit/f3a866b7e3cf5d0f218d4efd18c6a240b34669b5) on `dosemu` itself to perform the necessary resets:

> ```
> # disable xterm mouse tracking
> printf '\033[?1006l\033[?1003l\033[?1002l\033[?1000l\033[?9l'
> # disable xterm cursor keys
> printf '\033[?1l'
> ```

i.e.

```
ESC [?1006l ESC [?1003l ESC [?1002l ESC [?1001l ESC ?9l
ESC [?1l
```

Comment: `tput rs1` does both the clear screen and disables the mouse data. `tput rs2` clears the screen without disabling the mouse data. `tput rs3` and `tput rf` both neither clear the screen nor disable the mouse data. Thanks for the hints so far anyway, maybe the latter part of your answer will yield a solution.

Comment: Using your `infocmp` scriptlet I get `rs1=\Ec\E]104\007`. Only `printf '\ec'` seems to disable the mouse data, but it also clears the screen.

Comment: @ecm the other approach is to find the sequence that enables mouse capture. There will likely be a complementary sequence